# Multi master mysql with automerge data if node disconnected

Tags: mysql, distributed-databases

I have final project for my course about distributed system, so here the case :

> A company need 3 database server ( example : database a,b,c ) who
>   works together. So if someone insert a data to database a , the other
>   database ( b and c ) will have that data too. But when network
>   disconnected, the database server will work like standalone server.
>   But when network connected again, all data that inserted during
>   network disconnected, will distributed to other database. Example :
>   The database a disconnected to other database, and someone insert a
>   data  to database a. And after database a connected to other database,
>   other database will have that data again.

I try with galera, but it will fail to insert data when network disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera has the principle that a "quorum" in needed to declare that the cluster is alive.

For example if 'a' disconnects from 'b' and 'c', but 'b' and 'c' are still talking to each other, then

- b and c have a quorum (more than half the servers), so they declare they are the cluster.
- 'a' does not have a quorum, so it refuses to accept any writes.
- If the network gets repaired, 'a' will ask b & c for the latest updates and get back in sync.

That is Galera.  If you have plain MySQL multi-master, you have a nightmare when the network breaks.

NDB Cluster works a different way -- every node can be disconnected.  However, you must provide rules for "eventual consistency" of the data.

Comment: Ok i got it, thanks for explanation...